# How to Use Google apiKey to access google drive and google sheet in node.js

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am a node.js developer and have created some API's which access the google drive and google sheet using OAuthClient 2.0 but after a while it is giving error i.e.

```
User Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota. You may consider re-evaluating expected per-user traffic to the API and adjust project quota limits accordingly. You may monitor aggregate quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console.
Error Code: 403
```

And I don't want to increase my quota limits.

So i was thinking to use API-KEY (created for my project from [here:] (https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en)

```
   import {google} from 'googleapis';
   google.options({auth:"SOME API KEY"});
   const drive = google.drive({version: 'v2'}); 
   const childrens = drive.children.list((folderId:"{{folderId}}"));
```

But didn't worked at all as it needs user authentication with scopes to access google drive files.

can any one give me workaround?

Comment: The API key is used for accessing to the published contents. And also the API key can be used for only GET method. If you want to retrieve file list from the folder using the API key, the folder is required to be publicly shared. If you want to access to the folder without publicly sharing, please use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and/or Service account. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for this information , I think we can not use apiKey in google drive REST api's, So i moved to implement **exponential backoff** (actually i reduced the request rate/per second).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive api has a very generous quota limits.

your user limit is probably based on seconds(Default Per-user limit is:10/s)

You can change your default user quota limit in below link.
login needed

https://console.developers.google.com/project/bionic-path-686/apiui/apiview/drive/quotas

Comment: Thanks , I reduced the request rate i made ,and it was working fine for me.